# Why isn't this compiling?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    TCHAR buff[1024];
    GetLogicalDriveStrings(1024, buff);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; buff[i] != 0; i += 4)
        printf("%S", buff+i);
}
```

When I try to compile it with MSVC, I get the following errors:

http://ahb.me/5T-

Commenting out `GetLogicalDriveStrings(1024, buff);` causes the code to compile just fine

Comment: Maybe you should mention in the question that you're using C?

Comment: In his defense, it's tagged as `c` :)

Comment: and in the error messages, it's main.c :)

Comment: I was about to say compile it with `gcc -std=c99` but it seems you're on windows; check how to change the standard to `c99` on your compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Older version of C require local variables to be declared at the beginning of a block, before things like function calls. Move the `int i;` to the top of the function to be with the declaration of `buff`.

C++ did away with this requirement, as did C99.

Comment: `C requires local variables to be declared at the beginning of a block, before things like function calls. ` Thats not the case with C99. I think MSVC++ still doesn't support C99.

Comment: Added a note about C99 in addition to the one about C++.

Comment: That's really surprising that MSVC doesn't support C99, I usually only ever use C when I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    TCHAR buff[1024];
    GetLogicalDriveStrings(1024, buff);

    for(i = 0; buff[i] != 0; i += 4)
        printf("%S", buff+i);
}
```

Declare variables before calling functions in C.

Comment: I doubt it.. he trying to call Window function in C console program, without actually including lib file!

Answer (score 0):

move "int i" to the line before or after "TCHAR buff[1024]", or rename your main.c to main.cpp

btw, you should use _t series functions/macros once you decided to use TCHAR:

_tprintf(_T("..."))